# How to get code from last commit

Tags: git, github

I did two commits to the forked Github repo. Raised a pull request and merged that into parent Github repo. When I was testing it saw that code is not working correctly after that.

So I want the code which was there before these two commits.

I know that one way we can do is to revert the merge and get back the previous code.

But I don't want to do that I want to clone the github parent repo on my local machine and get back the previous code which was there before these two commits with out affecting parent repo. Is it possible?

If yes please help me with the commands.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `git diff <first commit ID> <second commit ID>` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and `git checkout <known working commit>` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to use the older version of the code locally. Consider a basic Git tutorial.

Comment: What is your end game here?  Do you plan to revert one or both commits?  Or, do you plan on adding a new commit to fix the problems?

Answer (score 2):

Try : git log command

```
git log
```

copy the commit hash on which you want to move : 
Eg:

```
commit 1ab8684337954909d8e82fc1a7674bacff0af959
Author: abc <abc@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 6 13:02:14 2016 +0530

git checkout 1ab8684337954909d8e82fc1a7674bacff0af959
```

you will move to that commit and you can check code in your working directory

Comment: Thanks I appreciate for your answer. I vote for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

All that you have to do is go on to the file that you committed on and go to the history for it, then select the earliest commit with the <> icon to view the code at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you all for your response.
Here how I solved the issue.

I cloned the repo on my local machine from parent repo. Then opened that on Git shell and used commands
         'git checkout commitid'
         'git checkout -b version0'

This is how I got the code before the previous two commits.

Once again I appreciate all for your time.